# Remove shades around objects in RGB image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have some images and want to detect around red-colored objects. but around blue object there is a red shade which is detected and is not true. how I can remove these red shades by filtering or processing image. any Matlab command or technical hints will be appreciated.
thanks

this is a sample object with unwanted red shade:
 http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=o7rmsg&s=8

I put a border around unwanted red shade here:
 http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28jefec&s=8

Answer (score 1):

```
I=imread('http://oi62.tinypic.com/o7rmsg.jpg');
I=imcrop(I,[200 100 400 250]);

Ir=I(:,:,1);
Ig=I(:,:,2);
Ib=I(:,:,3);
I1=Ib-Ir;
bw=im2bw(I1,graythresh(I1));
I2(:,:,1)=Ir.*uint8(bw);
I2(:,:,2)=Ig.*uint8(bw);
I2(:,:,3)=Ib.*uint8(bw);
imshow(I2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this code but the problem is not cropping blue area look at this image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zefsc8&s=8 green arrows show the desired objects red arrows show those unwanted shades which are too fade in this sample image but in some images like that one which is uploaded in the main post are more intense and detected as desired objects. this shades exists around blue objects on yellow or some how light orange background. I looking for a filter like sharpening or fading which can eliminate just those red shades not red desired objects.

Comment: cause I want to eliminate those red shades and process image as I am doing now which is successful in finding desired objects but this process finds shades too. Just need to remove shades to not be detected in addition to desired objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you are doing some sort of color segmentation and can get out a binary image (`BW`) showing all "red objects" detected in the image, some of which are your real objects, others which are the shades.

In this case it's fairly easy to do some checks on the nature of the detected objects, to filter out the incorrect matches, using `regionprops`.

`stats = regionprops(BW,'basic'); % 'basic', 'all', or specific list of properties to measure`

For example, if the "red shade" areas detected are always much smaller in overall than the real objects you're looking for, you can check the `'Area'` property and remove any detected parts which don't fit. Or you can calculate some other measure of the shape (`'Eccentricity'` or `‘Solidity’` for example), - e.g. if your real objects are roughly circular and solid then it should be pretty easy to tell the difference between that and the sort of area you show in your example image.

Comment: thanks for your hint yes exactly I want to do a segmentation and I did it successfully but now those shades are detected too and I have problem with eliminating them. my desired objects has wide variate forms and unfortunately most of them are curved and very similar to this red shades. I upload another image contain desired objects here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zefsc8&s=8#.UvVRjLSwROw.

Answer (score 0):

Take your image and convert it into its gray scale equivalent.
Now apply a general threshold to this image or apply a threshold with a particular value/percentage.By doing so, the small unwanted red pixels gets eliminated and now convert your new image back into rgb format. You can also try using some filters.